# Turning a char* into an uint8_t

Tags: c++, arrays, char, unsigned

Say I have an array that looks like:`{'0b00011000','0b10001000'}`
How do I convert each element within that array into a `uint8_t` keeping its output in binary format. (e.g. `'0b10001000' == 0b10001000`).

Are there functions that can over turn this, or will I have to make my own function?

p.s. I get a 'precision lost' error for casting, and when I bypass that obviously it loses its precision.

**Edit:** I did end up figuring out using bitsets instead of using `uint8_t`.

Comment: I don't think a char(8 bit signed) will lose its precision when it is converted into an 8 bit usigned data type

Comment: @muyustan i think its less of question of it actually losing precision and more  if the compiler can understand how to convert from one type to another simply though casting, which in this case it cant and if it tries it you won't get the right result.

Comment: @muyustan: So, you think the compiler is wrong in telling that there is a loss in precision? Please explain why. I do not understand. Thank you

Comment: @ArminMontigny I am no expert or so, however, If I don't understand something wrong, the integer value of a char is in between 0 and 127 for standard ASCII characters. At most between 0 and 255 for extended ASCII(and if it is unsigned char instead of char). So, [0,255] is also the range for an `uint8_t` then I think it is capable of holding the value of a char. **IF** the char variable is being used to only hold real characters, not negative values for example.

Comment: If you found out the answer to your question, please write an answer for those who might end up having the same problem in the future.

Comment: @muyustan ASCII does not come into this at all. OP isn’t encoding characters, they’re encoding eight bit binary values. Whether they’re in the range -128–127 or 0–255 is arbitrarily up to interpretation and does not impact the correctness of the output.

Comment: @FarhoodET sorry, new to this. The page suggestion was to put it below as an answer, so I did

Comment: @ArminMontigny Don't get me wrong I'm not an expert, this was simply speculation from the error warnings I was getting and me playing around with different 'types'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own answer:

You can use 'bitsets' within cpp and cast strings/char* within them

```
string s = "10011001";
std::bitset<8> binaryNum(string);
```

binaryNum will hold value 10011001, instead of converting to dec or hex.

Comment: Note that all parameters after your string are unnecessary, since they are suitably defaulted. So you can simpler write `std::bitset<8> bin_num{string}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```
uint8_t out = 0;
for(int i=2; i<10; i++)
    if(arr[i])
        out += pow(2, i-2);
```

Certainly not the best in terms of performance but if I understand the question it should work. But if you are worried about performance certainly you should look into why you are storing the value of a char into an array of 8 of it.

Comment: Thank you for not wanting to be rude.

`i=2` and `pow(2, i-2)` is due to is char array starting with `0b`.